# SQL Stored Procedure Get Distinct and Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

First let me start by saying I can do the below in .NET but I want it in the right place and putting less stress on the server. So I might be leanring towards .NET in the way I have tried to build it!

Query/Aim:

To show how many times a user (by EmployeeID) is in the TblTableList and then update the TblTableStatusCount

For now I am assuming the EmployeeID Exists. I have looked at varies example on stackoverflow, including cursors but to be honest I am a little confused and would be delighted with any guidance.

Also need to understand how to pass the value to @Status0Count etc..

Using: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (.NET2 in this case but usually 3.5 or 4)

Code:

```
 USE [Database]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spUpdatePassword]    Script Date: 07/16/2014 10:15:58 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spActionsDashboardSitesSummary]
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @EmployeeID NvarChar(10), --These may change to limited size i.e. 10
    @Status0 Int,
    @Status1 Int,
    @Status2 Int,
    @Status3 Int

    AS
    BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM [TblTableMain] 

      BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM TblTableList WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID  
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM TblTableList WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND CurrentAlertStatus = '0'
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM TblTableList WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND CurrentAlertStatus = '1'
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM TblTableList WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND CurrentAlertStatus = '2'

        -- Check if ID Exists       

        IF EXISTS (SELECT @EmployeeID FROM TblTableStatusCount WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID)

            UPDATE TblTableStatusCount 
            SET StatusTotalCount = @StatusTotal, Status0Count = @Status0, Status1Count = @Status1, Status2Count = @Status2
            WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
          Else
            INSERT INTO TblTableStatusCount 
            EmployeeID , StatusTotalCount, Status0Count, Status1Count , Status2Count) VALUES (@EmployeeID , @StatusTotal,@Status0, @Status1, @Status2 )
            WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID

        END

    END
```

I am more than happy to clarify anything

**EDIT - UPDATED CODE WITH SELECT and DECLARE**

```
  USE [database] 
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spUpdatePassword]    Script Date: 07/16/2014 10:15:58 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[spActionsDashboardSitesSummary]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @StatusTotal AS Int
DECLARE @Status0 AS Int
DECLARE @Status1 AS Int
DECLARE @Status2 AS Int
DECLARE @Status3 AS Int

--Cursor to loop through
DECLARE @PropertyID  AS NvarChar(10);
DECLARE propCurs CURSOR FOR
SELECT  PropertyID FROM [tbPropertyDetails]

--Open Loop Code
OPEN propCurs;
FETCH NEXT FROM propCurs INTO @PropertyID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
--Now do repeated code

  BEGIN

 --   SELECT @StatusTotal = COUNT(ID) FROM TblActions WHERE PropertyID = @PropertyID  
    --SELECT @Status0 =  COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM TblActions WHERE PropertyID = @PropertyID AND CurrentAlertStatus = '0'
    --SELECT @Status1 =  COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM TblActions WHERE PropertyID = @PropertyID AND CurrentAlertStatus = '1'
    --SELECT @Status2 =  COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM TblActions WHERE PropertyID = @PropertyID AND CurrentAlertStatus = '2'
    --SELECT @Status3 =  COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM TblActions WHERE PropertyID = @PropertyID AND CurrentAlertStatus = '3'

with cnt as ( 
   SELECT 
     1 as cntAll 
     , case WHEN CurrentAlertStatus = '0' then 1 else 0  end as cnt1
     , case WHEN CurrentAlertStatus = '1' then 1 else 0  end as cnt2
     , case WHEN CurrentAlertStatus = '2' then 1 else 0  end as cnt3
      , case WHEN CurrentAlertStatus = '3' then 1 else 0  end as cnt4
   from TblActions where PropertyID = @PropertyID
)
SELECT @StatusTotal = sum(cntAll),  
  @Status0  = sum(cnt1),
  @Status1  = sum(cnt2),
  @Status2  = sum(cnt3),
  @Status3  = sum(cnt4)
  FROM cnt;
    -- Check if ID Exists

    --HERE NEED TO CHECK IF EXISTS OR SHOULD I WIPE THE TABLE AT THE START? 
    IF EXISTS (SELECT PropertyID FROM [TblActionsCount] WHERE @PropertyID = PropertyID)

        UPDATE TblActionsCount 
        SET StatusTotalCount = @StatusTotal, Status0 = @Status0, Status1 = @Status1, Status2 = @Status2, Status3 = @Status3
        WHERE PropertyID = @PropertyID
      Else
        INSERT INTO [TblActionsCount] 
        (PropertyID, StatusTotalCount, Status0, Status1 , Status2, Status3) VALUES (@PropertyID, @StatusTotal,@Status0, @Status1, @Status2,@Status3 )

    END

    -- Now we bookend the loop code

    FETCH NEXT FROM propCurs INTO @PropertyID

END

--Tidy up and close loop code
CLOSE propCurs;
DEALLOCATE propCurs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assgin `@Status0,...` appropriate value. Try to do it that way:

```
SELECT @Status0 = COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM TblTableList 
  WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID;
SELECT @Status1 = COUNT( ...
```

Also, count query can be simplified with CTE (Common Table Expression):

```
; with cnt as ( 
   SELECT 
     1 as cntAll 
     , case WHEN CurrentAlertStatus = '0' then 1 else 0  end as cnt1
     , case WHEN CurrentAlertStatus = '1' then 1 else 0  end as cnt2
     , case WHEN CurrentAlertStatus = '2' then 1 else 0  end as cnt3
   from TblTableList where EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
)
select @StatusTotal = sum(cntAll),  
  @Status0  = sum(cnt1),
  @Status1  = sum(cnt2),
  @Status2  = sum(cnt3),
  from cnt;
```

I supposed, your ID is a unique Primary Key and therefore no `DISTINCT`filtering necessary

**EDIT:**

Cursor around the code above:

```
DECLARE @PropertyID int;
DECLARE propCurs CURSOR FOR  
SELECT PropertyID
FROM tbPropertyDetails;

OPEN propCurs
FETCH NEXT FROM propCurs INTO @PropertyID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN 
  ...--code here

  FETCH NEXT FROM propCurs INTO @PropertyID;  
END   
CLOSE propCurs;
DEALLOCATE propCurs;
```

Comment: Looks good but times out before moving second ID. I have amended Edited code to what I have now. I am also rereading encase I missed something

Comment: How many options are you processing? Try to implement `WITH cnt as ..` code I proposed you. Timeout might be caused by programming part(conn string Timeout option - if you use c# or smth. to call your SP)

Comment: Only 250 Id's to search through and then 1000 to search against. In .net takes seconds. Code update with cnt returns one line as nulls. Updated code edit to reflect.

Comment: Try to add into WHILE cycle PRINT expressions to determine what happenns and how long it takes to execute: `PRINT ' TIME [' + CONVERT( varchar, GETDATE(), 120 ) + ']';`

Comment: After 6 minuets nothing... FETCH NEXT FROM propCurs INTO @PropertyID

--Now do repeated codeWHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  

PRINT ' TIME [' + CONVERT( varchar, GETDATE(), 120 ) + ']';

Comment: remove `END -- Now we bookend the loop code` - it is recognized as WHILE's END => endless loop cycle executed

Comment: Brilliant, I really did appreciate all your time and patience with me today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same query as @StatusTotal but without distinct.That would fetch the number of times the user in the table.distinct always gives only '1' since we have id in where clause.